# Open source package that SUPPORTS all 3 major checkouts out of the box

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, amazon, checkout, google-checkout

Can you recommend an open source package that **supports** all 3 major checkouts out of the box?

By 3 major checkouts I mean:

1. PayPal Express
2. Amazon Payments
3. Google Checkout

Zen-Cart, for example, is great with PayPal, but it is a nightmare to setup and test with Google Checkout.

Does Joomla support all 3 major checkouts out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com) supports all 3 ([Full Features List](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/magento-feature-list.pdf), PDF):

- Integrated with Amazon Payments (Checkout by Amazon and Amazon Simple Pay)
- Integrated with multiple PayPal gateways:

  - Website Payments Standard
  - Website Payments Pro (Express and Direct)
  - Website Payments Pro UK (Express and Direct)
  - PayPal PayFlow Pro
- Integrated with Google Checkout (Level 2)
- Supports a lot of [payment gateways](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/features/payment/view) via extensions

Magento Community Edition is free and Open Source.

Comment: Thanks! +1. I have heard great things about Magento, but given the recent news that it was acquired by the company that owns PayPal, I don't know how this would affect their support in Amazon and Google Checkout. Are there additional options other than Magento?

Comment: Also, looking at the [Comparison Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/compare#comparison-chart) there are so many fundamental features missing, it's not even funny. I would be happy to learn about additional options other than Magento.

Comment: @uTubeFan Install and try for yourself -- that is the best way. You may like it or may not -- but decide **after** you did a test drive. RE: _possibly_ missing features -- sounds like you need **everything**. In any case -- this is the only one that I have worked with (last time over an year ago) -- in all our sites we use bespoke system where only needed features are implemented online and the rest (like reports, management etc) are handled by Windows desktop app.